# Search for an index inside an list

Tags: python, list

I have got two lists in python segmentation1 and segmentaiton2 which contains tuples of indexes for instace:

```
segmentation1 = [('874', '893'), ('964', '985')]
segmentation2 = [('901', '931')] # frame indexes in vid
```

and I have also and index with which i want to create and if-else statement, like the following

```
#pseudocode:
if index in segmentation1:
        ....
elif index in segementation2:
        ....
```

so to check if my index is inside the sequences from the tuples. How can I do so?

Comment: Is index a tuple or only one of the values?

Comment: just one value, index = 1000 for example.

Comment: A better example would help as 1000 doesn't occur in your posted examples. For instance, is the index '874' or '893'? That is, the first or second tuple-value.

Comment: I already did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You said in a comment, you want to see if your number is in the range of a tuple in your list.  You can achieve that result the same way:

```
s1 = [('874', '893'), ('964', '985')]
index = '879'

if [x for (x, y) in s1 if x <= index <= y]:
    print(True)
```

Output:

```
True
```

I would highly recommend either casting your tuples to ints, or casting before comparison.  For example, check out the following:

```
s1 = [('800', '1001')]
index = '1000'
if [x for (x, y) in s1 if x <= index <= y]:
    print(True)
```

This example will not output, since `'800' <= '1000' <= '1001'` will evaluate to `False`.  Casting to ints gives you the correct output.

To cast your tuples to ints:

```
[(int(x), int(y)) for (x, y) in s1]
```

Comment: But how can I cast the tuples to int?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you mean: Given

```
segmentation1 = [('874', '893'), ('964', '985')]
```

you want:

```
'874' in segmentation1 # true
'875' in segmentation1 # also true
'893' in segmentation1 # true
'894' in segmentation1 # false
```

if so, you can use the `any()` function to do that:

```
if any(lbound <= index <= ubound for lbound,ubound in segmentation1):
    pass # do something
```

But be careful. I see you use string as index in your example, so the comparison is based on string (i.e. '999' > '1000').

Answer (score 1):

If the value (index) you are searching for could be the 1st or 2nd value of the tuple then a primitive approach is:

```
segmentation1 = [('874', '893'), ('964', '985')]
segmentation2 = [('901', '931')] # frame indexes in vid

for (x, y) in segmentation1:
    if x == '893' or y == '893':
        print('found')
```

This is looking for the string '893' as an example. You would have to convert a numeric index to a string first.

Comment: (Although, it seems unusual that the search-value could appear at either position(?).)

Comment: Actually i didnt explain it really good. I want to search if my index is inside the tuples so between 874-893 964-985 etc.